# Is there a way to prevent partial word matching using Sitecore Search and Lucene?

Tags: search, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

Is there a way when using Sitecore Search and Lucene to not match partial words?  For example when searching for "Bos" I would like to NOT match the word "Boston".  Is there a way to require the entire word to match?  Here is a code snippet.  I am using FieldQuery.

```
bool _foundHits = false;
_index = SearchManager.GetIndex("product_version_index");
using (IndexSearchContext _searchContext = _index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    QueryBase _query = new FieldQuery("title", txtProduct.Text.Trim());
    SearchHits _hits = _searchContext.Search(_query, 1000);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try something like this to get the query you want to run. It will put the + in (indicating a required term) and quote the term, so it *should* exactly match what you're looking for, its worked for me. Providing you're passing in BooleanClause.Occur.MUST.

```
    protected BooleanQuery GetBooleanQuery(string fieldName, string term, BooleanClause.Occur occur)
    {
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(fieldName, new StandardAnalyzer());

        BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
        query.Add(parser.Parse(term), occur);
        return query;
    }
```

Essentially so your query ends up being parsed to +title:"Bos", you could also download Luke and play around with the query syntax in there, its easier if you know what the syntax should be and then work backwards to see what query objects will generate that.

Comment: No, it didn't work for me.  If I search on "Bos" it still returns items with "Boston" in the field.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the query in double quotes for the exact match results. Lucene supports many such opertators and boolean parameters that can be found here: http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on field type. If you have memo or text field then partial matching is applied. If you want exact matching use string field instead. There you can find some details: https://www.cmsbestpractices.com/bug-how-to-fix-solr-exact-string-matching-with-sitecore/ .